# Differential Coefficients

Tags: derivatives

Is this the correct answer and the correct workings out? Find the derivative:

[image]

$$ \frac{d}{dx}= f'g + fg' $$

$$ y = 3x^2 - \sin x $$

$$ \frac{d}{dx} [3x^2 - \sin2x] = 3.2x (\sin2x) + 3x^2 (\cos2x) $$

Answer (score 1):

This is weird!  Apparently the problem specifically says "using the Product Rule" but their is no "product" so no reason to use the product rule.  We are given $y= 3x^2- sin(2x)$ so that $dy= (6x- 2cos(2x))dx$.

(Well, you could treat "$x^2$" as "x(x)" and apply the product rule to that: $d(x(x))= (dx)(x)+ x(dx)= 2xdx$ but that is really stretching the point!  You could even think of $3x^2$ as "3(x)(x)" so that $d(3x^2)= d(3)(x)(x)+ 3(dx)x+ 3x(dx)= 0x^2+ 3x^2+ 3x^2= 6x^2$.

Comment: So this could be why ive been struggling? So was my answer wrong? Or did i not derive it enough?

Answer (score 0):

Is this now correct?? I think i now understand it.

[image]